# Как расшифровать ответ HTTPS? (nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, node-modules

Всем привет. Делаю автореггер для одного приложения и возникла проблема. (nodeJS, пакет needle для запросов)

Предыстория:
Сначала отсниффал приложение Fiddler'ом, но ответ от сервера не расшифровывался Fiddler'ом, хотя сертификат стоял. Погуглив я нашёл, что данное приложение не возвращает заголовок `Content-Encoding: deflate`, по-этому фидлер не понимает что ответ сжат и выводит кракозябры. Решил проблему небольшим скриптом для фидлера, который добавляет данный заголовок в ответ.

Собственно сама проблема:
Начав писать код я понял, что понятия не имею как привести к читаемому виду ответ сервера в коде. Кто-нибудь может подсказать? Запрос выполняется корректно 100%, потому что приходит письмо с подтверждением регистрации на почту.

Ответ сервера (на сколько я понимаю, сжатый с помощью алгоритма deflate):[image: Ответ сервера]

Код запроса:

```
needle.post(Endpoint + 'reg', authRequest, options, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log('[AUTH] Ошибка авторизации: ' + err);
    }

    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, собственно, ответ крылся в вопросе.

Нужно просто сделать операцию, обратную сжатию.

использовал zlib, вместо body использовал raw (там лежит Buffer)

```
zlib.inflate(response.raw, function(err, buf) {
                console.log("in the inflate callback:", buf);
                console.log("to string:", buf.toString("utf8") );
        });
```